# Angularjs: Understand how work $location

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new in Angular and i want to understand some function.
I've to redirect a button click in other page.
This is the code i need to replace:

```
function vaiAllaFattura(e) {        
    e.preventDefault();
    var dataItem = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));
    window.location.href = "@Url.Action("Create", "Fatturazione")" + "/?idPrestazioneAgenda=" + dataItem.Id;
}
```

this is the function i have to do in Angular when i click my button.
Someone can help me? Thank you!!!!

Comment: What are you trying to do? Redirect to an URL inside or outside the application?

Comment: Inside the project !!!!  i have to redirect to method "Create" in the controller "Fatturazione"....this controller is inside the main folder of the project...

Answer (score 0):

First thing, you could implement an `ng-click` on the button to pass the id of your row, to avoid using jQuery in your controller to retrieve it (this line `$(e.currentTarget).closest("tr")` should not be in the controller).

```
<tr ng-click="vaiAllaFattura($event)">...</tr>
```

Then you should not use the `window.location`, but use the `$location` service (see [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location) why).
So your final code should look something like:

```
$scope.vaiAllaFattura = function(e) {        
    $location.path("@Url.Action("Create", "Fatturazione")" + "/?idPrestazioneAgenda=" + e.currentTarget.Id);
}
```